# Changing an image when button click from another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, imageview

I want to be able to click a button on my settings fragment, which will change an image on another fragment called home fragment. My app keeps crashing once i click the button and im not sure why.

Settings Fragment :

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

public Button button;
public ImageView Torso;
public ImageView ShopGreenTorso;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Torso = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.Torso);
    ShopGreenTorso= (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ShopGreenTorso);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Purchased", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(SettingsFragment.this.getActivity(), AvatarFragment.class);
            //i.putExtra("resID", R.drawable.torso2green);
            Bundle b= new Bundle();
            b.putInt("resID", R.drawable.torso2green);
            SettingsFragment.this.setArguments(b);

            //setArguments(bundle);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
```

Avatar Fragment:

```
public class AvatarFragment extends Fragment {
public ImageView IV;
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_avatar, container, false);
    // init image view
    IV = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.Torso );
    // getting extras
    //Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
   // Bundle bundle=getArguments();
    Bundle b=getArguments();

    if(b!= null)
    {
        int resid = b.getInt("resID");
        IV.setBackgroundResource(resid);
    }
    return rootView;

}
}
```

I believe the error is coming from  IV.setImageResource(resid) but im not entirely sure, any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: where is the logcat output?

Comment: Just added it :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the exception, but it might be because Bundle mappings are case-sensitive.

Your `SettingsFragment` uses "ResId", but your `HomeFragment` is expecting "resID". If no mapping is found in the Bundle, you'll be given the default value of 0 for `resID`. It's possible that you're crashing when calling `IV.setImageResource(0);`.

Answer (score 0):

Your image implementation in code is wrong, you need to init your image view like this :

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_avatar, container, false);
        // init image view
        IV = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.Torso );
        // getting extras
        Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();

        if(bundle!= null)
        {
        int resid = bundle.getInt("resId");
        IV.setImageResource(resid);

        }
        return rootView;

        }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, i still get the same exception in my logcat ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass value from Fragment to Fragment directly.

You should use `setArguments` from SettingsFragment and `getArguments` in HomeFragment

Comment: So you're saying something like: Bundle b= new Bundle();
                b.putInt("resID", R.drawable.torso2green);
                SettingsFragment.this.setArguments(b);

Comment: @Fusiozii Yes.In `SettingsFragment`, when button onClick, callback to Activity and pass your value, and use `setArguments` in Activity where you trans to `AvatarFragment`, finally, use `getArguments` in `AvatarFragment` to get the value you pass from `SettingsFragment`.

Comment: Thank you :) I've updated my solution but i do not think the avatar fragement is even being called after the button click. Any ideas ?